# Flatten out keys into a single key and splitting their values by lists

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary like so:

```
{'a':['data', 1, 2, 3],
 'b':['data2', 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
 'c':['data3', 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

And I wanted to to be compressed likeso:

```
{'letters':['a','b','c'],
 'values':[['data', 1, 2, 3], ['data2', 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], ['data3', 3, 4, 5, 6]]}
```

Where `letters` and `values` can be any arbitrary names set for the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming:

```
d = {'a':['data', 1, 2, 3],
     'b':['data2', 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
     'c':['data3', 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

you can use:

```
out = {'letters': list(d.keys()),
       'values':  list(d.values())
       }
```

output:

```
>>> out
{'letters': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
 'values': [['data', 1, 2, 3], ['data2', 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], ['data3', 3, 4, 5, 6]]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use zip to combine your key names with the content of the dictionary items:

```
d = {'a':['data', 1, 2, 3],
 'b':['data2', 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
 'c':['data3', 3, 4, 5, 6]}

d = dict(zip(('letters','values'),zip(*d.items())))

print(d)
{'letters': ('a', 'b', 'c'), 
 'values': (['data', 1, 2, 3],['data2', 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],['data3', 3, 4, 5, 6])}
```